# How to overcome the error on join union tables with other table

Tags: google-bigquery

While we try to join between union tables on one side with other table on the other side,

```
SELECT A.x,B.y FROM ([DataSet.Liad],[DataSet.Livne]) AS A INNER JOIN [DataSet.Names] AS B ON A.ID = B.ID LIMIT 10
```

we get this error:

> Error: 2.1 - 0.0: JOIN cannot be applied directly to a table union or to a table wildcard function. Consider wrapping the table union or table wildcard function in a subquery (e.g., SELECT *).

In order to solve this error I suggest you to use a View.
Save this Query of union as a View, DataSet.LiadLivne:

```
SELECT * FROM [DataSet.Liad],[DataSet.Livne]
```

Execute the origin query using the view:

```
SELECT A.x,B.y FROM [DataSet.LiadLivne] AS A INNER JOIN [DataSet.Names] AS B ON A.ID = B.ID LIMIT 10
```

Enjoy

Answer (score 4):

You need to write as:

```
SELECT A.x,
       B.y
FROM
  (SELECT A.x
   FROM ([DataSet.Liad],[DataSet.Livne])) AS A
INNER JOIN [DataSet.Names] AS B ON A.ID = B.ID LIMIT 10
```

Comment: I know that I can use sub-query. The whole point in GBQ is sub-queries...
Imagine that I am extracting 40 attributes in the sub-query which is alias as "A".
I will need to re-write them again in the final output.
Hence, it will become to a query with 80 attributes....
which is not readable or aesthetically.
While using the view make it more simple and generic for further queries, While in your solution I will need to copy the same query format...
Views were build to ease our life.