# Joining date partitioned table give "'the_date' is not present in the GROUP BY list" error

Tags: google-bigquery

With this [answer in mind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31636778/How%20to%20overcome%20the%20error%20on%20join%20union%20tables%20with%20other%20table/31649330) I'm trying to query ga_sessions, summing some basic metrics after joining to my own custom reporting schedule. The custom reporting schedule maps a custom period (about 4 weeks) onto a date format YYYYMMDD and is in its own table.

Here's what I've come up with:

```
SELECT
  schedule.period,
  gadata.Visits,
  gadata.Pageviews,
  gadata.Transactions,
  gadata.Revenue
FROM (
  SELECT 
    gadata.date AS the_date, 
    SUM(totals.visits) AS Visits, 
    SUM(totals.pageviews) AS Pageviews,
    SUM(totals.transactions) AS Transactions, 
    SUM(totals.transactionRevenue)/1000000 AS Revenue
  FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE([project.table_prefix_],TIMESTAMP('2013-09-10'),TIMESTAMP('2013-09-12'))
  GROUP BY
    gadata.the_date
  ORDER BY
    gadata.the_date ASC
) AS gadata
JOIN 
  [project.reporting_schedule] AS schedule
ON
  gadata.date = schedule.GA_Date
GROUP BY gadata.the_date
```

But this gives the error: "Error: Expression 'the_date' is not present in the GROUP BY list"

I strongly suspect there's something wrong with my use of the syntax, I'm quite fresh with Google Big Query and the combination of querying a date partitioned table and join is throwing me.

What do I need to change to correct the code and sum the metrics by custom period?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ran into multiple issues. First is that with Table date range functions you cannot use alias, so you need to wrap into a select to use the alias further.

I replaced the `scheduled` table with a static writing, but you can replace with your own `select field from table` syntax

```
SELECT
  the_date,
  SUM(totals.visits) AS Visits,
  SUM(totals.pageviews) AS Pageviews,
  SUM(totals.transactions) AS Transactions,
  SUM(totals.transactionRevenue)/1000000 AS Revenue
FROM (
  SELECT
    [date] AS the_date,
    totals.visits,
    totals.pageviews,
    totals.transactions,
    totals.transactionRevenue
  FROM
    TABLE_DATE_RANGE([google.com:analytics-bigquery:LondonCycleHelmet.ga_sessions_],TIMESTAMP('2013-09-10'),TIMESTAMP('2013-09-12')) ) tt
JOIN (
  SELECT * FROM (SELECT '20130910' AS report_date), (SELECT '20130911' AS report_date)) schedule
ON
  schedule.report_date = tt.the_date
GROUP BY
  1
```

returns:

```
+-----+----------+--------+-----------+--------------+---------+---+
| Row | the_date | Visits | Pageviews | Transactions | Revenue |   |
+-----+----------+--------+-----------+--------------+---------+---+
|   1 | 20130910 |     63 |       249 |           16 | 206.23  |   |
+-----+----------+--------+-----------+--------------+---------+---+
```

Comment: Thanks, worked a charm! And managed to adapt it with no problem.